# Dynamically loaded CSS background-image not shown in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am making a github gist gallery for organizations, which you can see at [elsherbini.github.io/gist-gallery](http://elsherbini.github.io/gist-gallery).

The thumbnails are placed on the page by javascript, and the background image is set as an inline style rule. In Firefox and Internet Explorer the background image is shown, while in Chrome and Safari it is not.

In firefox, the following code returns the correct url of the background image, while in chrome it returns `"none"`:

`$($(".thumbnail")[0]).css("background-image")`

As a result I cannot use [the following fix by andrew cantino](http://blog.andrewcantino.com/blog/2012/02/15/fixing-the-chrome-background-refresh-bug/):

```
function refreshBackgrounds(selector) {
  // Chrome shim to fix http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/1b6a86d6d4cb8b04/739e937fa945a921
  // Remove this once Chrome fixes its bug.
  if (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.css("background-image")) {
        var oldBackgroundImage = $this.css("background-image");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $this.css("background-image", oldBackgroundImage);
        }, 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried adding single quotes to the url as some have suggested when similar issues have arisen for others. If I look at the network tab, it never even makes requests for the images. If I manually set the background image property as a new rule in chrome devtools, it works, so I know it is not an issue with the format of the url or a silly syntax error.

Is there a workaround to this bug in chrome?

Comment: I am likely wrong but I think `$this` is a in memory copy of `$(this)` and do not affect the DOM. Try replacing `$this` with `$(this)` inside the code?

Comment: `$this` still refers to the DOM node, it just avoids asking jQuery to look it up each time. I tried changing it, and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Oh well it was worth the try I guess XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also (or rather), in my browser the background-image styles are not parsed properly because of the missing closing parenthesis of the url() declarations. Fix that and then the background-image's can be retrieved using $().css().

*Details:* I see

```
 <a style="background-image: url(https://../thumbnail.png" class="gist thumbnail" href="..">
```

It should be

```
 <a style="background-image: url(//../thumbnail.png)" class="gist thumbnail" href="..">
```

Comment: This was the issue. It seems firefox and IE parsed the bad css anyway, but Chrome threw out the rule because of the issue with my underscore template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$this.css("background-image", oldBackgroundImage);` to `$this.css('background-image', 'url(' + oldBackgroundImage + ')');`

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. In firefox `oldBackgroundImage === "url("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/elsherbini/13383ffc376b54ad34ea/raw/55fbdfcf4d76dde2e6e3d1b638aacd47cd3aed33/thumbnail.png")"` (It already has the `url()` part). In Chrome, `oldBackgroundImage === "none"`

Comment: I was under the understanding that it works currently in firefox. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes it works in firefox. Just to make sure that the code worked though I ran it in firefox (without testing for the user agent) and it correctly reset the background-images. If you feel like it you can try for yourself, the link is at the top of the question.